# Is it possible to find the last element distance for each excel row?

Tags: excel, vbscript, ado, dao, adodb

Consider the below matrix:

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7
R1   x       x                        x
R2           x                x              x
R3                                                    x
R4           x        x       x
R5                                    x
```

Now using VBScript or ADO whichever will it be possible to find the distance of the last element of each row? ***Defination of distance*** distance is nothing but the count of number of cells after which the last element is placed in the given matrix. for e.g say -

- Dist(R1)=5
- Dist(R4)=4 like wise

I tried the below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ArrayListTaskDetails : Set ArrayListTaskDetails = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim i,colcount

i=2
Do while i < = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob.Rows(1))

colcount=objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob.Rows(i))
ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(colcount)

i=i+1
Loop

ArrayListTaskDetails.Sort()
i=ArrayListTaskDetails.Count
MsgBox("HighestColumnNumner:" & ArrayListTaskDetails(i-1))
```

But it is not working,as couldn't handle the in between blanks.

Thnaks,

Comment: @SiddharthRout please see my description,but it is not working!

Comment: Sure :) Looking at your code now...

Comment: I have both a vba as well as a formula solution... Let me test it completely. In the meantime you might want to see Ekkehard.Horner solution :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout formula solution will not work for me,as I am doing automation,rathe VBScript code will be more than sufficient! :)

Comment: I know ;) But I am going to use the formula in vbscript so that I don't do the dirty work... Let Excel do it :P Give me few moments... I want to test it completely before I post it...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Would you help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112068/can-vbscript-insertion-or-update-method-can-be-implemented-by-adodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way... Using Formulas in VBSCRIPT

```
Dim oXLApp, oXLWb, oXLWs

Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'~~> Show Excel
oXLApp.Visible = True

'~~> Open files (Change as applicable)
Set oXLWb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFile.xlsx")
Set oXLWs = oXLWb.Sheets(1)

Dim lRow, i, tmp

With oXLWs
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow
        tmp = oXLApp.Evaluate("=ADDRESS(ROW(A" & i & "),MATCH(INDEX($" & i _
        & ":$" & i & ",MAX(IF($A" & i & ":$K" & i & "<>"""",COLUMN($A" & i _
        & ":$K" & i & ")))),A" & i & ":K" & i & "),1)")

        MsgBox .Range("A" & i).Value & " :- " & .Range(tmp).Column - 1
    Next
End With
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Followup**

As per the request

```
Dim oXLApp, oXLWb, oXLWs

Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'~~> Hide Excel
oXLApp.Visible = True

'~~> Open files
Set oXLWb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFile.xlsx")
Set oXLWs = oXLWb.Sheets(1)

Dim lRow, i, tmp, MyArray, ColNo, ReturnName

With oXLWs
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row

    ColNo = .Columns.Count

    ReturnName = Split(.Cells(, ColNo).Address, "$", -1,1)(1)

    For i = 2 To lRow
        tmp = oXLApp.Evaluate("=ADDRESS(ROW(A" & i & "),MATCH(INDEX($" & i _
        & ":$" & i & ",MAX(IF($A" & i & ":$" & ReturnName & i & _
        "<>"""",COLUMN($A" & i & ":$" & ReturnName & i & ")))),A" & _
        i & ":" & ReturnName & i & "),1)")

        msgbox .Range("A" & i).Value & " :- " & .Range(tmp).Column - 1
    Next
End With
```

**More Followup**

```
Option Explicit

Dim oXLApp, oXLWb, oXLWs
Dim lRow, i, tmp, MyArray, ColNo, ReturnName

Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'~~> Hide Excel
oXLApp.Visible = True

'~~> Open files
Set oXLWb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFile.xlsx")

'~~> Set the Sheet 1 as sheet1
Set oXLWs = oXLWb.Sheets(1)

With oXLWs
    '~~> Get the last row in the worksheet
    lRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), -4123, 2, 1, 2).Row

    '~~> Get the total col count
    ColNo = .Columns.Count

    '~~> This will return the column name from column number
    ReturnName = Split(.Cells(, ColNo).Address, "$", -1, 1)(1)

    For i = 1 To lRow
        '~~> We are using the Evaluate to calculate the formula
        '~~> which will find our result
        tmp = oXLApp.Evaluate("=ADDRESS(ROW(A" & i & "),MATCH(INDEX($" & i _
        & ":$" & i & ",MAX(IF($A" & i & ":$" & ReturnName & i & _
        "<>"""",COLUMN($A" & i & ":$" & ReturnName & i & ")))),A" & _
        i & ":" & ReturnName & i & "),1)")

        '~~> This will return the column number
        MsgBox "Last Col in Row " & i & " is " & .Range(tmp).Column
    Next
End With
```

Comment: one question here is how it can be used for `n` number of columns?

Comment: I have taken it till "K". You can extend it to what ever your requirement is

Comment: can you just comment which are the section i need to chaange to fit my one with it?

Comment: just replace `K` with the relevant column number in `":$K" & i & "<>"""",COLUMN($A" & i _
        & ":$K" & i & ")))),A" & i & ":K" & i`

Comment: one more help,may i know if there is a chance to do the same with column number or not?

Comment: See you used `k` and can use the number of it which is `11` instead of `k`. i am asking you the same as in my case I have to run the logic 144 columns,so it would be better for me to use the column number instead of the `english` `alphabet`. is it possible?

Comment: that's the one I was looking for,but need a bit explanation of the line `.Range(tmp).Column - 1` - why `-1`?

Comment: Beacuse if the last value is in cell say E2, the column number is 5(A-B-C-D-E) but the Column header is actually one less which is 4 and hence we need to subtract it.

Comment: BTW I have updated the code. Now you do not need to change the column number. It will work for all scenarios.

Comment: i have no argue with your code,but would like to understand the logic for future! thus asking. still i am confused with the logic why `-1`?

Comment: What is `R1`? Does it depict Row 1 or is it a value in Cell A2 as shown in the snapshot that I have attached above.

Comment: got it now tightly,but it would be great if you explain the logic with `temp` varibale within the `code` with comments,it would be helpful for me to understand how the logic with `temp` works!! please do..

Comment: if you are going to change your code,please add another version, as i am looking the both the code,they are too much knowledgeble. so please don't delete them!

Comment: `yes R1 is a row, to make understandble I put it that way! ` In that case the above code logic changes slightly. There will be two changes `1` Finding the last row `2` We will now remove `- 1` from `.Range(tmp).Column - 1` I am also adding comments so that it is easier to understand :)

Comment: Sorry was having a quick bite :P Gimme 5 mins

Comment: Just one question what the difference is between `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row` and `lRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), -4123, 2, 1, 2).Row` ?

Comment: This should answer your question :) http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am really eager to learn the Excel-VBA this time. So could you help me by referring any good references on that. I have to start it from root level. I am totally unaware of its design and hot it works, and what we can do with Excel VBA.

Comment: @VBSolver: There are lot of free VBA tutorials online. If you want to buy a book then go with the book by John Walkenbach :)

Answer (score 2):

Given an ADODB connection to an .xls, a

```
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]"
```

that shows

```
PID     T1      T2      T3      T4      T5
11      1       <Null>  1       1       <Null>
14      1       1       1       <Null>  1
21      <Null>  <Null>  1       <Null>  <Null>
88      1       1       1       <Null>  <Null>
99      1       <Null>  <Null>  <Null>  <Null>
100     <Null>  <Null>  <Null>  <Null>  <Null>
101     1       1       1       1       1
```

a nested IIF(IsNull(Col), [...], ColNum) as in

```
"SELECT PID, IIF(IsNull(T5),IIF(IsNull(T4),IIF(IsNull(T3),IIF(IsNull(T2),IIF(IsNull(T1),0,1),2),3),4),5) As RMCol FROM [Sheet2$]"
```

will result in

```
PID     RMCol
11      4
14      5
21      3
88      3
99      1
100     0
101     5
```

**Trying to explain:**

The `IIF(BoolExpression, TrueValue, FalseValue)` expression evaluates to `TrueValue` if `BoolExpression` is True, to `FalseValue` otherwise; so putting another `IIF` in the True slot of the `IsNull(Colx)` will successively test the columns until a non-null column will trigger the return of the `FalseValue` (column number).

And yes: SQL is a tool to deal with an arbitrary number of rows (of a fixed/carefully designed set of columns); so if you made the design error of putting a logically unrestricted set of information into columns - instead of a(nother) table - that's the price you pay.

**Update:**

I hesitate to bring this up, because all hacks and shortcuts will fail in the long run - and than you have to start from the beginning with a decent design anyway, however:

a *recursive* function:

```
Function genIFF(n)
  If 1 = n Then
     genIFF = "IIF(IsNull(T1),0,1)"
  Else
     genIFF = "IIF(IsNull(T" & n & ")," & genIFF(n - 1) & "," & n & ")"
  End If
End Function
```

will happily create:

```
  Dim n
  For n = 1 To 5
      WScript.Echo n, genIFF(n)
  Next

1 IIF(IsNull(T1),0,1)
2 IIF(IsNull(T2),IIF(IsNull(T1),0,1),2)
3 IIF(IsNull(T3),IIF(IsNull(T2),IIF(IsNull(T1),0,1),2),3)
4 IIF(IsNull(T4),IIF(IsNull(T3),IIF(IsNull(T2),IIF(IsNull(T1),0,1),2),3),4)
5 IIF(IsNull(T5),IIF(IsNull(T4),IIF(IsNull(T3),IIF(IsNull(T2),IIF(IsNull(T1),0,1),2),3),4),5)
```

or even:

```
50 IIF(IsNull(T50),IIF(IsNull(T49),IIF(IsNull(T48),IIF(IsNull(T47),IIF(IsNull(T46),IIF(IsNull(T45),IIF(IsNull(
T44),IIF(IsNull(T43),IIF(IsNull(T42),IIF(IsNull(T41),IIF(IsNull(T40),IIF(IsNull(T39),IIF(IsNull(T38),IIF(IsNul
l(T37),IIF(IsNull(T36),IIF(IsNull(T35),IIF(IsNull(T34),IIF(IsNull(T33),IIF(IsNull(T32),IIF(IsNull(T31),IIF(IsN
ull(T30),IIF(IsNull(T29),IIF(IsNull(T28),IIF(IsNull(T27),IIF(IsNull(T26),IIF(IsNull(T25),IIF(IsNull(T24),IIF(I
sNull(T23),IIF(IsNull(T22),IIF(IsNull(T21),IIF(IsNull(T20),IIF(IsNull(T19),IIF(IsNull(T18),IIF(IsNull(T17),IIF
(IsNull(T16),IIF(IsNull(T15),IIF(IsNull(T14),IIF(IsNull(T13),IIF(IsNull(T12),IIF(IsNull(T11),IIF(IsNull(T10),I
IF(IsNull(T9),IIF(IsNull(T8),IIF(IsNull(T7),IIF(IsNull(T6),IIF(IsNull(T5),IIF(IsNull(T4),IIF(IsNull(T3),IIF(Is
Null(T2),IIF(IsNull(T1),0,1),2),3),4),5),6),7),8),9),10),11),12),13),14),15),16),17),18),19),20),21),22),23),2
4),25),26),27),28),29),30),31),32),33),34),35),36),37),38),39),40),41),42),43),44),45),46),47),48),49),50)
```

Visual proof reading and testing from what n Excel will choke on the nesteds IIFs is left as exercise for masochists.

Comment: couldn't understand the logic,can you explain it also?

Comment: and If I have 50 columns then should I need to write all in this nested way?

Comment: I am sorry, you are 100% right! so any chance to make the nested condition to be simple or generalized?

Comment: Nice one it is. But now i am thinkng how would I connect it to the ADODB with the above posted by you! Any help in this regard? It seems your full code with the `ADO` one will be more helpful for me to understand the full logic.. Again `fantastic logic` you have provided but just a bit scattered!

Comment: i am too much interested to see your code, so may I have it in the full format, to understand it more clearly all the breaking s of its.